# Count resources through another?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

Here area my relationships:

```
Account has_many :emails
Email has_many :recipients
Email belongs_to :account
Recipient belongs_to :email
```

What I want to do is count how many recipients any given account has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `:through` relationship in your `Account` model like this:

```
class Account
  has_many :emails
  has_many :recipients, :through => :emails
end
```

Then you can do this:

```
Account.first.recipients.count
```

Hope it helps